# What kit (if any and not WebAPI) to use to write RESTful APIs for services that can only run on 3.5 framework?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, asp.net-3.5

I have a web app hosted on x64 app-pool (32-bit not allowed) that needs to call a 3.5 framework dll provided by a vendor. Neither of those constraints are under my control. Desiring json as model for my request/response, I need to write RESTful api's that will serve that dll to my web app. I realized WebAPI kit does not apply to me because they required 4.0 frameworks, what is my alternative?

Comment: Why do you think Web API needs to be on an x64 framework? And why are you not capable of searching for ASP.NET REST API tools yourself?

Comment: Shouldn't have said 64.  See my question again. Maybe you can still answer it.  Thanks

Comment: Okay, so now you constrained it to .NET 3.5. Again, why are you not capable of searching for these tools yourself? Asking for tool recommendations is specifically off-topic here. And anyways, a REST API is extremely simple in concept. Why not try implementing your own?

Comment: I'm doing it right now. Once I found myself the answer, I will post it here.  Thankyou.

Comment: Take a look at WCF REST.

Comment: Thanks.  I have included a link to acquire a WCF REST starter kit in my posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF REST supports restful web services prior to .NET 4.0. See: [A Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services with WCF 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Tool to write your own WCF on 3.5 frameworks for REST :

[WCF REST STARTER KIT](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/WCF-REST-Starter-Kit.shtml)

On install, you will see

```
Microsoft.Http.dll 
Microsoft.Http.Extensions.dll
Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.dll
```

in the dir: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WCF REST\WCF REST Starter Kit Preview 2\Assemblies

[image: 3.5 Svc Support]

[MORE ...](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/JI2X050413-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-API-and-WCF-REST-and-Web-Service.html)

1. To use WCF as WCF Rest service you have to enable webHttpBindings.
2. It support HTTP GET and POST verbs by [WebGet] and [WebInvoke]
   attributes respectively.
3. To enable other HTTP verbs you have to do some configuration in IIS
   to accept request of that particular verb on .svc files
4. Passing data through parameters using a WebGet needs configuration.
5. The UriTemplate must be specified It support XML, JSON and ATOM data
   format.

[JSON formatter for 3.5](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Dec/29/DataContractJsonSerializer-in-NET-35)

```
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;  //System.ServiceModel.Web

    Me[] sizes = new Me[] { new Me{ radius = 34, height = 66 }, new Me{ radius = 24, height = 68 } }; // Me [DataContract]
    DataContractJsonSerializer szr = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof(Me[]) );   
    MemoryStream toJSONBuf= new MemoryStream();
    szr.WriteObject( toJSONBuf, sizes );        
    string strJSON = Encoding.Default.GetString(toJSONBuf.ToArray());
    toJSONBuf.Close(); 
    //Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode( strJSON ));
    // REVERSE: the same serializer
    toJSONBuf= new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes( strJSON ));
    sizes = szr.ReadObject(toJSONBuf) as Me[];
    toJSONBuf.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question is combining these two documentation

[Implementing the URI Design with UriTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)

[How to: Create a Basic WCF Web HTTP Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx)

The first article is pretty long with no focus but the second one is pretty good.  The only other help you need is editing the .config which you should use WCF edit tool provided by VS.

[Example using WCF Config editor](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/37db1d/create-your-first-restful-service-with-wcf-3-5/)

[source code](http://dotnetmentors.com/wcf/wcf-rest-service-to-get-or-post-json-data-and-retrieve-json-data-with-datacontract.aspx)